# How can I add a geolocation mark and do a zoom there in a Cluster Marks of Nokia Maps?

Tags: javascript, here-api

This is the example that I've been using:
[Nokia Maps Cluster](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Nokia_Maps_API_-_How_to_cluster_map_markers)

But I couldn't add a new mark of geolocation I've tried with the HTML5 API but I think I don't how to implement it, I hope somebody could tell me what I need to change. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a point to a cluster you need to call **clusterProvider.add()**, to add a series of points just use **clusterProvider.addAll()** instead, Each of these methods take an **IClusterPoint** (or an array of **IClusterPoints** ), which is basically means they will accept any object with a longitude and latitude.

If you really want to add a geolocation to your cluster you'll need to do the following steps:

1. Make an HTML5 geolocation call as in this example [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Nokia_Maps_API_-_Show_user%27s_current_location_details_%28Address%29_in_an_info_bubble)
2. Instead or then reverse geocoding, take the response and add it to
       your cluster.

The actual clustering is triggered by the method  **clusterProvider.cluster()** as shown:

```
clusterProvider.addAll(markers);
clusterProvider.cluster();
```

see the [API documentation](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.clustering.ClusterProvider.html#topic-apiref__ClusterProvider-add) for more details.